# TextInputType.numberWithOptions doesn't show comma or dot

Tags: flutter

```
TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
```

I'm using the above code as a `keyboardType` in my `TextFormField` but in some devices, the device doesn't display comma or dot. Screenshot is given below:

[image: keyboard image]

Thinking of using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/virtual_keyboard

Any idea on how to solve it?

This doesn't solve my problem because in my case, it's happening on Android.
[Flutter TextField with number keyboard, comma is needed instead of period (Only iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55570414/flutter-textfield-with-number-keyboard-comma-is-needed-instead-of-period-only)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter TextField with number keyboard, comma is needed instead of period (Only iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55570414/flutter-textfield-with-number-keyboard-comma-is-needed-instead-of-period-only)

Comment: My problem is on the samsung device. It works fine with iPhones and new Android phones.

Comment: Try checking this issue: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1898

Comment: @MangaldeepPannu Seems like there's nothing I can do besides implementing a virtual keyboard

Comment: Was you abble to fix the problem? Could you please post your answer?

Answer (score 11):

This parameter will solve the problem

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
```

Comment: Look at the very first line of my question. I've already give that parameter.

Comment: looks like device-specific issue, I have encountered the problem that I have 
and dot and comma on some devices - and they are conflicting

Comment: I think it's related to the localization. Some countries use decimal, some use dot.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe a bit late. This will solve all numbers problems:

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true, signed: true)
```

Here `signed: true` param will make your IOS keyboard the one in which you will have decimal points in it along with numbers. Trust me and check it out with it.

Comment: This saved my day. I believe this is the best option, along with `FilteringTextInputFormatter ` because you don't have to account for locale differences.

Answer (score 3):

It's a well known *Android* issue in Samsung Keyboards 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61175

#### TLDR;

Usually the work-around is to fallback to text keyboard.

I developed a package with this work-around to easy get the keyboard vendor name and then make some crafty `if samsung then TextInputType.text` 
package: keyboard_name 
However, it don't solves the problem.

#### Long and ***cooler*** way

First: Format Inputters 
*note: I didn't find a way to enable the comma*

Convert the inputted dot to comma and don't worry about the disabled comma 
To do this you need to extend a Text Input Formatter

```dart
class CommaFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
    TextEditingValue oldValue,
    TextEditingValue newValue,
  ) {
    String _text = newValue.text;
    //This is only if you need signed numbers. Will convert the first '.'(dot) to '-'(minus)
    //if (_text.isNotEmpty && _text[0] == '.') 
    //  _text = _text.replaceFirst('.', '-');
    return newValue.copyWith(
      text: _text.replaceAll('.', ','),
    );
  }
}
```

Also, you can put another *smartass* regex to format after this one

```dart
TextFormField(
    inputFormatters: [
        CommaFormatter(),
        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(
                          //r'^[-]{0,1}[0-9]*[,]?[0-9]*', //signed regex    
                          r'^[0-9]*[,]?[0-9]*', 
                        ),
                      ),
    ],
    /.../
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On iOS you have to enable the de (or any other locale than en_US) locale in the ios build settings even for flutter apps.

1. Open the IOS folder in your flutter project
2. Inside the IOS folder open Runner.xcworkspace folder with xCode.
3. Click on the runner you will see bunch of option, click on info and under the Localization native development region select United States.
4. Rebuild the project
   [Here is the image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cr2Z.png)