# How to get which focusNode is currently focused in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I need to know which `focusNode` is currently focused in Flutter.

Let me explain why I need that.

I'm using `virtual_keyboard` package because I have an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58802772/textinputtype-numberwithoptions-doesnt-show-comma-or-dot?noredirect=1#comment103911981_58802772) with the numeric inputs.

```
            child: VirtualKeyboard(
          onKeyPress: (VirtualKeyboardKey key) {
            if (key.action == VirtualKeyboardKeyAction.Backspace) {
              _priceController.text = _priceController.text
                  .substring(0, _priceController.text.length - 1);
            }
            _priceController.text += key.text ?? "";
          },
          type: VirtualKeyboardType.Numeric,
        ),
```

I have two `TextFormField`'s(price and amount) and when user changes the focus, `onKeyPress:` method needs to edit the text of another `TextEditingController`. If I know which `focusNode` is currently active, maybe I can do it.

Comment: If possible you can use TextField in place of TextFormField, since it has a focusNode property. If yes I can post the solution.

Comment: I'm already using TextFormField, check my question. I can pass focusNode but I want to know which focusNode is currently active. Imagine I have two TextFormFields and I've requested focus for one. If the other TextFormField is active, I want to know.

Answer (score 2):

Use `FocusNode? _focusNode = FocusScope.of(context).focusedChild`;

Answer (score 1):

Refering to [FocusNode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html)

Use `focusnode.hasFocus`
It returns a `true` if node has input focus.

Comment: its only work with first come , when we have 3 text field ( 3 focus node ) its only trigger on first click , focuseNodeNext doesnt work to detect if we click next

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the [FocusNode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html) instance of a focusable widget (e.g. TextField) with `FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus`.

This was far more reliable, for me, than `focusNode.hasFocus`.

```
// initalize focusNode
FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();

    
...
 
// add focusNode to TextField or any other fousable widget
child: TextField(
  focusNode: focusNode,
); 

... 

if(focusNode == FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus){
  // focusNode (TextField) is focused right now
}
```