# Issue with Flutter iOS Keyboard: "." Character Missing in TextInputType.number

Tags: ios, flutter, keyboard

I'm facing a problem with Flutter where the "." (decimal point) character is missing from the keyboard when using TextInputType.number on iOS devices. I have set up the input formatters correctly to allow only digits and the "." character, but still, the "." character is not visible on the keyboard. Here's my code snippet:

```
Container(
                                              width: 65.w,
                                              height: 6.w,
                                              child: TextFormField(
                                                // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
                                                controller:
                                                    _currentWeightController,
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                                inputFormatters: [
                                                  FilteringTextInputFormatter
                                                      .allow(RegExp('[0-9.]')),
                                                ],
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 20,
                                                    color: Colors.black),

                                                // decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                //   hintText:
                                                //       '${num.parse(measurementRes[targetWeight] ?? "0").ceil().toString()}',
                                                // ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
```

The code works perfectly on Android, showing both digits and the "." character on the keyboard. However, on iOS devices, the "." character is not visible on the keyboard. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you running your posts through an AI tool for grammar improvement?  If so, be really careful with that, as AI tools tend to insert phrases in the text that you didn't originally include yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your code, you are using: [`TextInputType.number`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputType/number-constant.html)

> ... Optimize for unsigned numerical information **without a decimal point**.

```
...
keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
```

You should instead use:

```
keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
```

---

```dart
Container(
      width: 65.w,
      height: 6.w,
      child: TextFormField(
        // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
        controller: _currentWeightController,
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
        inputFormatters: [
          FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[0-9.]')),
        ],
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),

        // decoration: InputDecoration(
        //   hintText:
        //       '${num.parse(measurementRes[targetWeight] ?? "0").ceil().toString()}',
        // ),
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced this before :) Instead of using `keyboardType: TextInputType.number`, use:

```
const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
  {bool? signed = true/false,
  bool? decimal = true/false}
)
```

Reference: Official document: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputType/TextInputType.numberWithOptions.html

**Edit 1**: I found a problem in Samsung phone bases on this post: [TextInputType.numberWithOptions doesn't show comma or dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58802772/textinputtype-numberwithoptions-doesnt-show-comma-or-dot). The answer & GitHub issue is under answers, you should notice that.

**Edit 2**: Oh I just realize, in my Vietnam, we use "," for decimal point. But your formatter using "." for decimal point, therefore my keyboard is showing up "," button but cannot be pressed. Is this your problem?

Comment: I'm not sure if my implementation of your solution is correct, as I'm getting an error. Would you mind implementing it yourself and showing me the correct way to do it with the code I provided?

Comment: sure pal, try to replace like this: `keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),` if not, try to remove inputFormatters

Comment: I tried that solution and even removed inputFormatters as you suggested and I'm still not seeing the decimal button. I just saw your edit, no that isn't my problem at all. My problem is that I don't even see the button, and yes, we use ".", that is what I'm trying to get. I only see the digits and the backspace button.

Comment: damn, restart your macbook & iphone :) I just test in my simulator but there's no problem. You're ghosted bro

Comment: I was accidentally placing the solution into the wrong file, your solution does in fact work, no more misery :)