# Flutter: allow decimals with comma

Tags: flutter

To allow decimals on inputs I do this:

```
TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true)
```

And that works... but only for dots. For example, in Spanish, comma is used instead of dot and the numeric keyboard shows this. When I click the comma nothing happens and users are not allowed to use decimals.

Is possible to fix this with `numberWithOptions` or I need to use a different method?

Comment: Looks similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58802772/textinputtype-numberwithoptions-doesnt-show-comma-or-dot). You probably need to set the locale to Spanish.

Comment: I think that's different: "in some devices, the device doesn't display comma or dot". I do display dot and comma (depending on the device) but only first one works

Comment: Yes, it's not exactly the same but it's probably related to the same underlying problem, i.e., wrong locale settings. Did you try to set the locale as described in the linked post or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55570414/flutter-textfield-with-number-keyboard-comma-is-needed-instead-of-period-only)?

Comment: I tried to add the languages in Runner.xcodeproj but it's a String, not a dropdown as the screenshoot shows. Also, following this approach, how do I know what languages I need to add? I know Spanish uses comma but not sure how many languages out there does